# Has anyone tried dumping MySQL data on windows directly to MySQL on linux?

Tags: mysql, dump

windows:

```
mysqldump .... > windata.sql;
```

linux:

```
mysql ... < windata.sql
```

Will the data be cross-platform?

Comment: shouldn't this be on serverfault?

Comment: why? It's not about mysql servers configuration, it's about using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done so, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

should be. actually, even the actual files in the datadir are supposed to be portable (but you need to be careful when copying them, shut down your server first).

Answer (score 1):

One issue you should be aware of is that by default table names are case insensitive on Windows and case sensitive on Linux. This could be a huge pain (at least it was for me). You can alter it by setting `lowercase_table_names` (or something like this) in my.cnf on linux

Answer (score 1):

No problems experienced myself.  Some of the alternative encodings may be interesting, as well as case-sensitivity on table names - so check those carefully. But if you're just doing UTF8 and double check the names, you should be fine.

Like all new things, trying it will give you the most accurate answer, let us know what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Crossplatform will probably work. But be aware of encoding issues. ÄÖÜ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it.  No problems moving between Windows, Solaris, or Linux.